# Angular modify and resubmit http.get request using buttons on page

Tags: angularjs

I'm pulling data from elastic search using Angular http.get and displaying the output using angular.

The initial concept is working fine, however what I would like to do is add a button to the page to be able to run a frequently required query which will modify the data that is displayed and exclude records containing specific words or phrases.

I think that this can be achieved by having the button set the value of a variable within the scope of the http.get request and then resubmititng the get request.

So far I have:

```
<body>
       <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="RemoveEntires" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.input1">
    <input type="button" value="RemoveEntries containing text" ng-click='DocView()'>
</form>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('DisplayDoc', []);
    var baseUrl = "http://elasticserver:9200/app/_search?q=product:balls";
    var queryURL = baseUrl + "+!color:"; + formData.input1;
    var completeURL = queryURL + "&sort=DateTime&size=1000&default_operator=AND";
    app.controller('DocView', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({method: 'GET', url: completeURL})
        .success(function(response) {$scope.jsondata = response.hits.hits;});
    });
</script>
```

If I enter "red" in the form, I would like it resubmit the http.get request to elasticsearch which would then exclude the red balls from the balls products that are returned.

This is not currently working for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.

Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.search = '';
    var baseUrl = "http://elasticserver:9200/app/_search?q=product:balls+!color:";

    $scope.submit = function() {
        $http.get(baseUrl + $scope.search + "&sort=DateTime&size=1000&default_operator=AND")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.jsondata = response.hits.hits;
            });
    }
});
```

And then build the form like this:

```
<form novalidate>
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Search</button>
</form>
```